# Training Tesseract-OCR for english language fonts

Tags: ocr, tesseract-ocr

I have about 3000 small images of single words that I am trying to convert to text.
I have installed tesseract on my windows 7 machine using the installer and successfully managed to OCR images throught cmd and powershell.

```
 tesseract.exe imagename.png imagename
```

produces a text file with the converted text.

The results I got were terrible with only about 40% of characters successfully converted. 
I would like to improve the results.

Does anyone know what the optional configurations that can be given in this command?
The required arguments are:

```
tesseract imagename outputbase [- lang] [configfile [+|-]varfile]...]
```

Also could someone describe the training procedure, I am finding it hard to understand the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3). I know that my text is in times new roman. Do I need to train it for TNR or is that already built in and/or is it possible to download files that allows tesseract to recognize it?

Comment: I found some docs for training http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

Comment: After reading the instructions that @andrew (you) found, what part are you not understanding?  How far have you gotten in that process?

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove the results is to preprocess them like remove any skew and thresholding them. You can use open CV. Later you can train the text